# The changes of my solution made in Blazor Wasm do not load for me

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, razor, blazor

I have been working with blazor in a practical way watching a tutorial. When I added the new option TO TWO and changed the titles to the view everything worked fine.

Now, when I started to touch the view a little more adding more features, when I reload the view, it doesn't reflect the changes.

It should be noted that the IDE does not show me errors or warnings, I did the tutorial several times to read letter by letter in case I have errors, I do not, and I cannot find the solution.

I tried deleting the Bin and OBJ folders but it doesn't work.

This is a snippet of the default NavMenu.Razor document which is where I add the To Dos option to the view

```
<div class="nav-item px-3">
    <NavLink class="nav-link" href="todo">
        <span class="oi oi-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span> To Dos
    </NavLink>
</div>
```

My Razor document that I created

```
@page "/todo"

    <PageTitle>Mis To Dos</PageTitle>
    <h1>To Dos Pendientes: (@toDos.Count(todo => !todo.EstaCompletado))</h1>

<table>
    <thead class= "py-5">
        <th class="col-lg-3">Completado?</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3">Titulo</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3">Contenido</th>
        <th class="col-lg-3">Fecha de Entrega</th>
    </thead>

    @foreach(var toDo in toDos)
    {
        <tr>
            <td><input type="checkbox" @bind="toDo.EstaCompletado"/></td>
            <td>@toDo.Titulo</td>
            <td>@toDo.Contenido</td>
            <td>@toDo.FechaEntrega</td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>

<h2>Añade Nuevos To Dos</h2>

<input placeholder="Añadir Titulo" @bind = "nuevoTitulo"/>
<input placeholder="Añadir Contenido" @bind="nuevoContenido" />
<button @onclick= AddToDo >Añadir To Do</button>

@code 
{
    private string? nuevoTitulo;
    private string? nuevoContenido;
    private List<ToDoItem> toDos = new(); 
    private void AddToDo()
    {
        // Añade el To Do
        if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(nuevoTitulo))
        {
            toDos.Add(new ToDoItem { 
                Titulo = nuevoTitulo, 
                Contenido = nuevoContenido , 
                FechaEntrega = new DateOnly(2022,1,31)
            });
            nuevoTitulo = string.Empty;
        }
    }
}
```

My class that is used for the above:

```
public class ToDoItem
{
    public int TodoItemId { get; set; }

    public string? Titulo { get; set; }
    public string? Contenido { get; set; }
    public string? Responsable { get; set; }
    public List<string> Etiquetas { get; set; } = new List<string>();
    public DateOnly? FechaEntrega { get; set; }
    public TimeOnly? HoraEntrega { get; set; }
    public bool EstaCompletado { get; set; } = false;

}
```

The wrong result is this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SrFP.png)

This is the App.razor document that contains that error. I'll leave the coding in case it helps.

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
        <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)" />
        <FocusOnNavigate RouteData="@routeData" Selector="h1" />
    </Found>
    <NotFound>
        <PageTitle>Not found</PageTitle>
        <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
            <p role="alert">Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
        </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
</Router>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u9Oe9.png)

Comment: Is your page in the same solution or a library? Also not related to the error your table does not have a `<tbody ...`

Comment: ¿How can I see that it is in the same solution? @BrianParker . I placed the image of the solution explorer in case it helps you to the question you ask me

Comment: I asked as it needs special treatment if was not. But as it is I would then look inside the projects `.csproj` to see if your `.cs` file is being treated differently.

Comment: @BrianParker Can you give me an example a little more descriptive?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved. I don't have the technical answer, but I fixed it by deleting the ToDo.razor component and create another as Todo.razor.

The possible error was that in full development, I changed the name to .razor after having compiled the solution under the name of Todo.razor , so I assume that from here the problem was generated.

Recommendation: do not change the names of your files, after you have made compilations.

Likewise, I thank those who participated to help me.

See you soon ;).